# What do I do with the Inbox folder in the Documents Directory if I want the User to Be Allowed to Manage Folders and Files?

Tags: swift, import, file-manager

I have an application in which users are able to use a file manager to create, modify, and remove directories as well as files. I notice that when importing files from external applications, a system folder `Inbox` is automatically generated preventing users from both deleting the folder and/or naming a folder called `Inbox`. Should I instead create a subdirectory in the Document path directory and have the file manager consider that folder as the document root path? How do other apps achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there's a best practice on this. Just do what makes most sense to you. I just ignore the Inbox and/or filter it out when grabbing a list of files. Using a subdirectory as you've suggested would certainly be a good solution as well though.

Comment: @MattLong Well darn. Before I question Apple's filesystem design, I have to wonder why that folder gets made in the document path and made visible to the app user in the first place. Either a design flaw or there is clearly some kind of benefit to placing the Inbox folder there that I am unaware of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are allowing users to create their own documents and directories within your Sandbox's Documents Directory, it might be good to do what you suggested and create a separate directory within Documents that will be designated for user-editable data.

For example, perhaps add a 'User' directory within Documents, and then use that as the root directory for user files and directories.

Apple's documentation states the following about /Documents/Inbox:

> Use this directory to access files that your app was asked to open by outside entities. Specifically, the Mail program places email attachments associated with your app in this directory. Document interaction controllers may also place files in it.
>   Your app can read and delete files in this directory but cannot create new files or write to existing files. If the user tries to edit a file in this directory, your app must silently move it out of the directory before making any changes.
>   The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

From the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH1-SW1).

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but not the most elegant solution.  I suppose I just have to create a psuedo "chroot" jail within the Documents directory?

Comment: I suppose that's one way to go about it. You could also probably create your own function that would return the path or url for the new root directory and use that in your code to retrieve the path/url instead of the system functions that return the path to the documents directory.

Comment: yes that's what I currently have implemented right now. Thanks for your input. Perhaps Apple will address this in the future. +1 for citing the documentation